Finding an integer random variable $N \geq 0$ such that $\mathbb P(N>0) = e^{-10}$ and $\mathbb E N = e^{10}$
Give an example of an integer random variable $N \geq 0$ such that $\mathbb P(N>0) = e^{-10}$ and $\mathbb E N = e^{10}$.
How should I approach this? Here is my attempt (that got nowhere) with a power series expansion:
$$
\begin{align*}
e^{10} - e^{-10} = \mathbb E N - \mathbb P (N>0) &= \sum_{n\geq 0} n \mathbb P(N=n) - \mathbb P(N \geq 1)\\
 &= \sum_{k\geq1}\sum_{n\geq k} \mathbb P(N=n) - \mathbb P(N\geq 1)\\
&= \sum_{k\geq1} \mathbb P(N\geq n) - \mathbb P(N\geq 1)\\
&= \sum_{k\geq1} \mathbb P(N> n)\\
\end{align*}
$$
On the other hand $e^{10} - e^{-10}  = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{10^{n} - (-10)^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{10^{n} - (-10)^{n}}{n!}$. But we cannot assign $\mathbb P(N>n) := \frac{10^{n} - (-10)^{n}}{n!}$, since this isn't strictly nonincreasing and has terms greater than 1.

Intuitively, $N$ is very likely to be $0$, but the expectation is large, so the nonzero values must be very large.  Aside from the fact that $N$ takes only integer values, you could take $N=e^{20}$ with probability $e^{-10}$ and be done.

@RossMillikan But $N$ is an integer random variable, it should take on integer values.

Suppose $N$ only has support on $-1$ and some positive integer.  How close to the properties can you get?  Can you fiddle with this setup (maybe split the left mass on $-1$ and $-2$ and maybe split the mass way off to the right) to fine-tune the expectation value?

I noted that.  You need to find a set of values and probabilities for each that give the desired expectation.  You don't need the pdf to be nonincreasing.  The cdf will be but you should be working on the pdf.

Clearly one can create random variables which are supported on strict subsets of the natural numbers and satisfy the above estimates (for example, take $N=0$ with probability $1-e^{-10}$ and $N=e^{20}$ with probability $e^{-10}$. This can also be written as $e^{20}Ber(e^{-10})$).
If you want a random variable that's elementary but supported entirely on the natural numbers, then consider the following experiment. Flip a blue coin which comes up heads with probability $1-e^{-10}$. If it comes up heads, then stop. If it comes up tails, then consider an independent red coin which has probability $r$ of coming up heads, and keep flipping it till it comes up heads for the first time. Let $N$ be the random variable representing the number of times the red coin was tossed (including the final coin toss which came heads).
Note that with probability $1-e^{-10}$, $N=0$. Otherwise, with probability $e^{-10}$, $N$ is distributed as a geometric random variable $Geo(r)$. Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}(N =k) = \mathbb P(\text{blue coin was tails } \cap Geo(r) = k) = e^{-10}(1-r)^{k-1}r$$
for all $k\geq 1$, and $\mathbb{P}(N=0) = 1-e^{-10}$. One easily checks by the law of iterated expectation that $$
\mathbb E[N] \\= \mathbb{P}(\text{blue coin was heads})\mathbb E[N | \text{blue coin was heads}] + \mathbb{P}(\text{blue coin was tails})\mathbb E[N | \text{blue coin was tails}]\\
= (1-e^{-10}) \times 0 + e^{-10} \times \mathbb E[Geo(r)] = \frac{e^{-10}}{r}.
$$
Thus, if $r = e^{-20}$, then $$
\mathbb P(N>0) = e^{-10} \text{ and } \mathbb E[N] = \frac{e^{-10}}{e^{-20}} = e^{10}. 
$$

Okay, I suppose we could slightly modify a now-deleted answer to make this work. We can just rig the support to be ${0,\ell,k}$ to satisfy:
$$
\begin{cases}
\ell\mathbb P (N=\ell) + k\mathbb P (N=k) = e^{10} = \mathbb E N\\
\mathbb P (N=\ell) + \mathbb P (N=k) = e^{-10} = \mathbb P (N> 0) \\
0\leq\mathbb P (N=\ell) \leq 1\\
0\leq\mathbb P (N=k) \leq 1\\
\end{cases}\
$$
For example, fix $\ell = 1$ and then pick $k$ so that $\mathbb P (N=k) = \frac{e^{10}-e^{-10}}{k-1}\leq e^{-10}$, so that $e^{-10}-\mathbb P(N=k)=\mathbb P(N=1) \geq 0$. E.g. $k=\lceil \frac{e^{10} - e^{-10}}{e^{-10}} + 1\rceil$.
I think this is a little underwhelming, though.
